# Testing domain-name availability with pythonwhois

Tags: python, domain-name, whois

I'm using successfully `pythonwhois` (installed with `pip install ...`) to check the availability of .com domains:

```
import pythonwhois
for domain in ['aaa.com', 'bbb.com', ...]:
    details = pythonwhois.get_whois(domain)
    if 'No match for' in str(details):   # simple but it works!
        print domain
```

But:

- it is a little bit slow (2 requests per second on average)
- won't I be blacklisted by the `whois` server if I do 26*26*26 ~ 17000 requests?
  (I'm testing availability of `???mail.com` with `?` being `a..z`)

**Question: is there a better way to check availability than doing one `whois` request per domain?**

---

Edit: The job finished in 9572 seconds, and [here is the full list](https://pastebin.com/nD8WYjT7) of all domains available of the form `???mail.com`, as of November 2017, if anyone is interested to start an email service!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should parallelize what you are doing. Since most of the time spent by your function is waiting, you can verify a lot of works at once (not limited to your number of processors). Example:

```
import pythonwhois
from joblib import Parallel, delayed, cpu_count
n_jobs = 100 # works in parallel
def f(domain):
    details = pythonwhois.get_whois(domain)
    if 'No match for' in str(details):   # simple but it works!
        print(domain)
        return domain
    else:
        return None

domains= ['aaa.com', 'bbb.com', 'ccc.com', 'bbbaohecraoea.com']
result = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=10)(delayed(f)(domain) for domain in domains)

# create a list with the available domains
available_domains=[domains[idx] for idx,r in enumerate(result) if r!=None]
print(available_domains)
# Result
# ['bbbaohecraoea.com']
```

Comment: Waw, this looks very nice, I never used `Parallel` before! (Just an error with your code: `ImportError: [joblib] Attempting to do parallel computing without protecting your import on a system that does not support forking. To use parallel-computing in a script, you must protect your main loop using "if __name__ == '__main__'". Please see the joblib documentation on Parallel for more information`)  (I use Python 2.7 with Windows).

Comment: So I added `if __name__ == '__main__':`, and then it runs, but then I have no other output than `[Parallel(n_jobs=10)]: Done   5 tasks      | elapsed:    1.7s
[Parallel(n_jobs=10)]: Done  12 tasks      | elapsed:    2.1s
[Parallel(n_jobs=10)]: Done  21 tasks      | elapsed:    2.5s
[Parallel(n_jobs=10)]: Done  30 tasks      | elapsed:    2.6s`. Any idea about how to actually display the results? I think the `print` don't have any effect.

Comment: I added a little more of code to show you the available domains. Also, in my case, there is no error while importing. It probably is a version problem or something.

Comment: Oh I see, it's not displayed on the fly, but at the end, when printing the `result`... Is there a way to print the domains on the fly (while doing it) before the end? It seems that the `print(domain)` in `f()` doesn't show.

Comment: Maybe it is because of the version you use. With my version under linux it works. But what you're interested is only the result. Just to play around I created [another script](https://pastebin.com/WwQ6U2PD), that creates 10000 random strings and checks it.

Comment: Ok, maybe the numbers were really ambitious. I changed to `n_jobs=100` and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Yes 100 is far better, 1000 produced a massive freeze / forkbomb (hundreds of python32.exe process in the task manager!)